# How to get rid of data frame name in `deparse(substitute())`?

Tags: r, dataframe

Just like in question: How to get rid of data frame name in `deparse(substitute())`?

For example, create a simple function:

```
foo<-function(x){
  print(
    paste(
      'This is called', deparse(substitute(x))
      )
    )
}
```

Feeding it with a vector gives desired behaviour:

```
test<-1:3
foo(test)
[1] "This is called test"
```

But when I pass a column of data frame it includes data frame name:

```
> df<-data.frame(ones=c(1,1,1), twos=c(2,2,2))
> foo(df$ones)
[1] "This is called df$ones"
```

How to get rid of this `df$` in output to get `"This is called ones"` (hopefully with no use of regular expressions)?

Comment: Call it like this: `with(df, foo(ones))`

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is... not very pretty ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this seems not to put this into the function but to use he function that was presented in the question like this:

```
with(df, foo(ones))
```

Of course, one could modify the function to remove everything up to $ but there are other ways to specify this such as `DF[["ones"]]` and this line of fixing it up seems to get into an endless hole of finding new situations that have to be fixed up.

```
# not recommended
foo2 <- function(x) {
  Name <- sub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(x)))
  print( paste('This is called', Name) )      
}
DF <- data.frame(ones = 5:6)
foo2(DF$ones)
## [1] "This is called ones"
```

Really the problem is the design of `foo`. Functions such as `lm` that involve column names and data frames use a call which separates them:

```
foo3 <- function(x, data = parent.frame()) {
  Name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  print( paste('This is called', Name ))
  data[[Name]]
}

ones <- 3:4
foo3(ones)
## [1] "This is called ones"
## [1] 3 4

DF <- data.frame(ones = 5:6)
foo3(ones, DF)
## [1] "This is called ones"
## [1] 5 6
```

or another design would be to specify the column as a formula:

```
foo4 <- function(formula, data = parent.frame()) {
  Name <- all.vars(formula)[1]
  print( paste('This is called', Name ))
  data[[Name]]
}
DF <- data.frame(ones = 5:6)
foo4(~ ones, DF)
## [1] "This is called ones"
## [1] 5 6

ones <- 4:5
foo4(~ ones)
## [1] "This is called ones"
## [1] 4 5
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! `foo3` is something I was looking for!